# watch changes for incremental build using webpack and gulp for angular 5 app - AOT

Tags: angularjs, webpack, gulp, aot

In order to compile my angular app AOT, I'm using webpack and gulp.
I noticed that the watch step of webpack is not working so well, sometimes work and sometimes not, and when it work the files are not being updated on the site.

Please see the code bellow and tell me if there is anything I can do with minimum changes? or should I have to write something new?

packages.json

```
  {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp build:dev",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3",
    "npm": "4.0.5"
  },
  "license": "LicenseRef-LICENSE",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "url": "git+ssh://gitolite@my-app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "1.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "0.3.4",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "jasmine": "2.8.0",
    "jstz": "1.0.9",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.13",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "xlsx": "0.11.7",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.6",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "custom-tslint-formatters": "2.1.1",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-add-src": "0.2.0",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-exec": "2.1.3",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-ignore": "2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "3.1.1",
    "gulp-jsonminify": "1.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "6.3.0",
    "gulp-preprocess": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.4.1",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "1.3.6",
    "gulp-tslint": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "3.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "3.0.8",
    "karma-typescript-es6-transform": "1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.6",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.3",
    "postcss-scss": "0.4.1",
    "precss": "1.4.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "webpack": "2.2.1"
  }
}
```

gulp.js - the main tasks

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    addsrc = require('gulp-add-src'),
    config = require('./gulp.config.js'),
    del = require('del'),
    tslint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    preprocess = require('gulp-preprocess'),    
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    webpackConfig = config.webpack,
    webpackCompiler = webpack(webpackConfig),
    karmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    cachebust = require('gulp-cache-bust'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
    gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore'),
    jsonminify = require('gulp-jsonminify'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('build:dev', function (callback) {
  runSequence(
    'clean', 
    'copy:assets',
    ['html:index', 'sass:styles', 'tslint', 'typescript:dev'],
    ['watch'],
    callback
  )
});

gulp.task("typescript:dev", function(callback) {
    var initialBuild = true;

    webpackCompiler.watch(null, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) 
        {
            throw new gutil.PluginError("typescript:dev", err);
        }
        if (stats.hasErrors()) {
            console.log(stats.toString("errors-only"));
        }

        if (initialBuild) 
        {
            initialBuild = false;

            // notify gulp that the initial task is done (now watching for changes)
            callback();
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("typescript updated");
        }
    });
});
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './my-app/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './my-app/vendor.ts',
        'main': './my-app/main.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../dist',
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', '.html', '.scss'],
        enforceExtension: false
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader", options: { exclude: /\.async\.html$/} },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:[
                    {loader:"raw-loader"},
                    {loader:"postcss-loader", options:{syntax:"postcss-scss", plugins: postcssConfig}},
                    {loader:"sass-loader", options:{outputStyle:"expanded"}}
                ]
            }
        ],
        noParse: [/angular2\/bundles\/.+/]
    },

    plugins: [
        new AotPlugin({tsConfigPath: 'my-app/tsconfig.json', entryModule: __dirname + '/../my-app/my-app/app.module#AppModule', debug: true}),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills']}),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/, "doesnotexists")
  ]
};
```

when I run npm start I expect that webpack will be watch any changes in ts files and rebuild only those that changed.

Again thank you